# OK, let's clean up these STM32 tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup, tag-synonyms

**Note: This has already been completed. I'll leave the question for reference :)**

Some time ago, I asked [this question](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6801/38335) about how we should handle the stm32 tags ([stm32f1](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stm32f1), [stm32f2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stm32f2), etc). The overwhelming response was that **we should merge them all into the existing [stm32](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stm32) tag**.

Before we do this, of course, we should set up tag synonyms (background [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/70710)). I've just gone in and proposed synonyms for most of these tags.

There are a few things left for us to do:

1. Go and approve the [synonyms](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms), if you agree.
2. Delete a bad synonym proposal I made a long time ago. It is no longer the correct way to do things, and it is keeping us from proposing the correct synonyms. I assume that a mod can do this? The tags in questions are [stm32f10x](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stm32f10x) as a synonym for [stm32f10](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stm32f10).
3. Once that is done, we can propose (and accept) new [stm32](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stm32) synonyms [stm32f10x](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stm32f10x) and [stm32f10](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stm32f10).
4. After some time has gone by, a mod can merge the tags if it seems appropriate.

Does this sound like the thing to do?

Comment: You want the stm32f1 <- stm32f10x suggestion deleted? I can just do that now if you like.

Comment: Thank you, @W5VO, that would be excellent!

Comment: Actually, looking at it, I wouldn't mind just approving these suggested synonyms as there seems to be overwhelming support for it (+18/-1).

Comment: @W5VO I thought that might be the case, but I didn't want to presume :-)  Fine by me, of course. Also, I see you took care of the old suggestion, so I just made the new ones. Thanks for everything.

Comment: Why was [tag:stm32cubemx] not merged in with the rest? The sole purpose of this tool is to aid STM32 hw & sw development.

Comment: @berendi At first glance, I wouldn't include it because we are just looking at including hardware in this tag, and that's a software development tool. I'm welcome to other opinions, though.

Comment: @berendi Yeah, my thoughts were similar to W5VO's. But I don't disagree with you - maybe it should be merged... It looks like you have enough stm32 rep to suggest a tag synonym. Then, to speed things along, you may want to ask a Meta question to draw attention to it.

Comment: @berendi Oh, haha, I see you already did that :) Sorry!  For anyone looking, the proposed sysnonym is [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tags/stm32/synonyms).

Comment: @W5VO The software development tool is called STM32CubeIDE. STM32CubeMX assists hardware development, from selecting the right STM32 MCU with a given set of resources, assigning pin functions and resolving conflicts, checking clock rates, calculating power requirements, and then it can generate initialization code stubs that are specific to the chosen STM32 MCU.

Comment: @berendi To me, that still sounds like it would be better matched with the software side than the hardware, but I'm not familiar with the STM32 ecosystem. I would prefer to either let it live as a suggested synonym (and have *users* approve it), or ask a separate question and get some consensus.

Comment: I am with W5VO on the STM32CubeIDE / STM32CubeMX; it can have it's own very 'interesting' issues when generating code that are not quite the same as hardware issues so from my perspective it should really keep it's own tag.

Comment: OK, I'm convinced.

Comment: I went ahead and closed this as we basically completed the goals of the linked question.

Comment: Sounds good, @W5VO, thank you. What is your opinion on doing a tag merge now that the synonyms are in place?

Comment: It may be time to do this again, there's now `stm32f103c8t6` with 34 questions(!), `stm32f103` with 16, `stm32h750vbt` with 3, `stm32f407` with 3, `stm32l433cc` with 3. _Inexplicably,_ `stm32f103c8t6` is synonymed to `stm32`, _not_ `stm32f103` nor `stm32f10x` nor `stm32f`. :/ Many of those tags seem overly specific, although the numbers of questions under some of them are quite high, for whatever reason.